# Find and print permissions command in a csh file

Tags: shell-script, shell, find, chmod, csh

Trying to create a `.csh` file that can find and display permission of the files in the directory.

Using the following content of the script

```
#!/bin/csh -b

find . type -f \( -name "*.sh" -o -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" -o -name "*.pl" -o -name "*.py" \) \
    -printf "depth="%d/"sym perm="%M/"perm="%m/"size="%s/"user="%u/"group="%g/"name="%p/"type="%Y\\n
```

This does not seem to work as I do not get any output when sourcing the script.
Is there any better way to do this script ?

Comment: Is it really `type -f`? If yes, try changing it to `-type f` (with the dash before `type`, not before `f`)

Comment: @mosvy You are correct. it should be `-type f`. The command works on terminal but does not when i source it in a `.csh` file

Comment: Anything other than the most trivial of `csh` scripts will come back to bite you. It really is worth learning `sh` or `bash` if you want to get into scripting.

Comment: The `-printf` line - are you sure you mean `/` and not `\ `? If you do mean `/` then why have you got all those double quotes in the string? They won't appear in your output